# Beamer-like description environment

Tags: beamer, lists, description

Where can I find the definition of the description environment available in `beamer`? I'd like to replicate it for my own needs in an article-oriented document. I'm interested in its right-left alignment features:

[image: right-left alignment features]

Comment: BTW there is `beamerarticle`.

Comment: `$ latexdef -F -c beamer description` tells me:
`\description first defined in "/usr/local/texlive/2010/texmf-dist/tex/latex/beamer/beamerbaselocalstructure.sty".`

Comment: What about it do you want to replicate? You might be able to do enough with just `enumitem` or similar, rather than drawing out all the beamer code you'd need to use beamer's version...

Comment: I'm interested in the alignment features of the beamer description environment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend using the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package which allows customizing list environments such as `description`. If you would edit your question specifying what's exactly desired, you could get an example.

The `mdwlist` package is an alternative focussing on description lists.

Here's a solution without these packages for right aligned description labels:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand*{\desccolor}{blue}
\newcommand*{\widestlabel}{}
\newcommand*{\setwidestlabel}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\widestlabel}{#1}}
\renewcommand\descriptionlabel[1]{%
  \hspace\labelsep\parbox[t]{%
    \widthof{\widestlabel}}{\raggedleft\textcolor{\desccolor}{#1}}}
\begin{document}
\setwidestlabel{Second Item}
\begin{description}
\item[First Item] Description of first item
\item[Second Item] Description of second item
\item[Third Item] Description of third item
\item[Fourth Item] Description of fourth item
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sometimes it really sucks that TeX is inherently one-pass so you can't automatically determine the widest label. That is, without doing some really ugly stuff involving yet another auxiliary file. Nice solution though. Probably for descriptions longer than one line a somewhat more complicated solution ought to be invoked, however, to indent following lines correctly.

Comment: @Christian: It is relative simple to run two pass algorithms in TeX without the need for an auxiliary file. In fact, environments like `align` and `tablularx` do that. The fact that the item environment does not do so is a design decision and not an inherent limitation of TeX. For a counter example, see my solution.

Answer (score 3):

This answer is just to illustrate that it is possible to automatically calculate the width of the widest label. In ConTeXt this is done by passing `fit,broad` parameter to `\setupitemize`. For example:

```
\defineitemgroup
  [leftdescription]
  [
    distance=0.5em,
    color=blue,
    itemalign=flushright,
  ]

\setupitemgroup
  [leftdescription]
  [fit,broad]

\starttext


Some text before the list
\startleftdescription
  \sym{First Item} Description of first item
  \sym{Second Item} Description of second item
  \sym{Third Item} Description of third item
  \sym{Fourth Item} Description of fourth item
  \sym{Fifth Item} This is to show that the indentation 
      of the subsequent lines is done correctly. 
\stopleftdescription
Some text after the list

\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]